# Move a group of files to a new folder if their file names, minus extension, matches?

Tags: bash, recursion, match, grouping, filenames

I have a folder full of files that have the same name but different file extensions. For example:

```
file-1.ai
file-1.svg
file-1.pdf
file-2.ai
file-2.svg
file-2.txt
file-3.ai
file-3.svg
example-1.pdf
example-3.mov
```

Is there any way in Linux (any programming language will do) I can move the group of files to a new folder (either a new folder per file group or all in one folder) if their file names, minus extension, matches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think you want something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="/somedir/"
for i in "$dir"*; do
  if [ -f "$i" ]; then
    filename="${i%%.*}"
    if [ ! -d "$filename" ]; then
      mkdir "$filename"
    fi

    mv "$i" "$filename"
  fi

done
```

e.g.

```
$ tree /somedir
/somedir
├── example-1.pdf
├── example-3.mov
├── file-1.ai
├── file-1.pdf
├── file-1.svg
├── file-2.ai
├── file-2.svg
├── file-2.txt
├── file-3.ai
└── file-3.svg

$ ./above_script

$ tree /somedir
/somedir
├── example-1
│   └── example-1.pdf
├── example-3
│   └── example-3.mov
├── file-1
│   ├── file-1.ai
│   ├── file-1.pdf
│   └── file-1.svg
├── file-2
│   ├── file-2.ai
│   ├── file-2.svg
│   └── file-2.txt
└── file-3
    ├── file-3.ai
    └── file-3.svg
```

Comment: Thanks! That mostly does what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this script:

```
for i in *.*; do
   d="${i%.*}"
   [[ ! -d "$d" ]] && mkdir "$d"
   cp "$i" "$d"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways this can be done. One solution would be to simply use the move command:

`mv file-1.* /new/directory`

This will move all files named `file-1` regardless of extension to the new directory.

Comment: I've expanded the question to indicate that the files may have different names instead of "file-". Could you provide a method that works regardless of file naming structure?

Comment: @hellocatfood Just `mv * /new/directory/` ? Though see my answer if you want to make dirs with the filenames.

Comment: If that's the case you would do the same like `mv example-1.* /new/dir`

Comment: Yes, that would work but I want to do it automatically for all files in my directory

Comment: @hellocatfood `*` expands to all files in your directory. If you're getting some errors, please be more clear about what isn't working.

Comment: I think the misunderstanding is that I don't want to move all files. Only "if their file names, minus extension, matches". So, files that have no match aren't moved.

Comment: @hellocatfood If they "match" what? You have different filenames in the example you posted.

Comment: For some of the examples, the file names _minus the extension_ are the same. file-1.ai, file-1.svg and file-1.pdf, _minus the extensions_ are the same

Comment: @hellocatfood I modified the example in my answer to have exactly the same files as yours. If output is not what you're trying to do, then you really need to re-word the question.

Comment: If @BroSlow's answer is not what you want I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, I'll try rewording my question