# bash create dir with basename of files, then move corresponding into

Tags: bash, for-loop

so I have problem with kinda easy thing:
I have thousands of files which have the same basename, but different extensions(multiple of them). For example I have following:

```
t_2dri.manual.ali_porter.inseq  
t_2dri.manual.ali_porter.inseq.porter   

t_2dri.tm.ali_porter.inseq 
t_2dri.tm.ali_porter.inseq.porter       

t_3ezm.manual.ali_porter.inseq  
t_3ezm.manual.ali_porter.inseq.porter

t_8gep.fast.ali_porter.inseq 
t_8gep.fast.ali_porter.inseq.porter
```

what I'd like to get are directiories:

```
t_2dri.manual.ali
t_2dri.tm.ali
t_3ezm.manual.ali
t_8gep.fast.ali
```

and I do this with the following script:

```
for i in *.porter;do
    bn=$(basename $i _porter.inseq.porter)
    mkdir $bn;done
```

which works(maybe I can do it better/shorter) ?

the second question is HOW to put the files into correct folders - I tried few scripts and for loops, but no succes yet.

---

OK, so I got half of the answer I need,but some of them are truly mistifing, now to make it easier for us (me :) ) to understand:

I do have folders named

```
folder1.sth
folder2.sth
folder3.sth
```

and in the same directory I do have files like:

```
   folder1.sth.sth.blah
   folder3.sth.other.thing 
   folder1.sth.any.other.thing
```

how to put every file which is *.sth.* into corresponding *.sth folder (with the same prefixes)

---

ok, SUNDAY AFTER DINNER IS THE COSMIC TIME OF THE WEEK

what worked for me (although I can SWEAR it didn't half an hour ago) is:

```
for i in *.sth;do
    mv $i.* $i;
    done
```

---

ok, so what I was doing wrong is that

```
for i in *.ali;do
  2     mv $i_* $i;
  3     done
```

is not the same as

```
for i in *.ali;do
  2     mv $i.* $i;
  3     done
```

in the way that $i.* is something that was $i it has . later and something after, while $i_ means completly different thing - don't know what yet and how to omit it, maybe somebody will help ?

Comment: Please do not scrunch the `done` up onto the same line as a command in the loop (unless the whole loop is on one line, which is usually not a good idea either).

Comment: Also, separately, the term 'basename' has a specific meaning in shell, based on the command called `basename`.  It refers to the last component of a path name, the whole of the word after the last slash (or the whole word if there is no slash).  I'm not quite sure what the alternative should be: maybe 'common prefix'?

Comment: aaam, yep, I used the basename command here, to get the names without the extensions... I guess, cause it works, or maybe I'm misinterpreting of what you're saying

Comment: @Strumillo I think you're misinterpreting what the for-loops you're trying now are doing. `for i in *.ali`. *.ali will expand first to a space separated list of files strictly ending in ali (files containing ali don't match), then the for loop will loop over each file, and you will get for example i="file1.ali", i="file2.ali", i="file3.ali". Then your `mv` command will try to expand to all files starting with for exmple "file1.ali" followed by a ".", possibly followed by "some more text" and try to rename them "file1.ali", which I don't think is what you want.

Comment: @Strumillo See my update. I think this is what you were trying to do for your sth case if you know all the directories are made before hand. You still want to check [ -f file] so it only tries to copy regular files and not the directories themselves

Answer (score 1):

```
for base in t_2dri.manual.ali t_2dri.tm.ali t_3ezm.manual.ali t_8gep.fast.ali; do
    mkdir $base
    mv "${base}*" $base/
done
```

If you are getting `argument list too long` errors because there are zillions of files, you just have to loop over them, thusly:

```
for base in t_2dri.manual.ali t_2dri.tm.ali t_3ezm.manual.ali t_8gep.fast.ali; do
    mkdir $base
    for file in ${base}*; do
        mv "$file" $base/
    done
done
```

Comment: yeeeeeep, but I cannot list t_2dri.manual.ali t_2dri.tm.ali t_3ezm.manual.ali t_8gep.fast.ali , there are like 500 thousands of such files, but we're getting pretty close, the  mv ${base}* $base/ thing should do

Comment: You can convert the loop to `for f in *.ali_*; do mv "$f" "${f%.ali_*}.ali/"; done`

Comment: ... Assuming that the real problem is that you cannot `mv` all files at once because you get "argument list too long". The shell can expand the wildcard just fine, but the list is larger than the memory available for passing to a subprocess, aka `ARG_MAX`. But a `for` loop over the list of matched files is fine, because the shell does not pass the list to another program. See also http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/

Comment: no, the ARG_MAX is not the issue, but thank you, I'll keep foe the future (should be useful). The issue is also with loop you proposed - it doesn't work, I tried the same thing before - now it's trying to mv stuff to .ali/ folder, not the corresponding-prefix.ali/ folder

Answer (score 1):

I answered a very similar question here [Move a group of files to a new folder if their file names, minus extension, matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619044/move-a-group-of-files-to-a-new-folder-if-their-file-names-minus-extension-matc/20620653#20620653) A slight change below should work for what you want.

To get the filename in this case, you can use this in bash

```
"${i%%.ali*}.ali" #This will match the longest possible match of ".ali*" in the string and remove it, leaving everything before it, and then we append ".ali" back to the end.
```

So modifying the script from the other answer to what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="/somedir/"
for i in "$dir"*; do
  if [[ -f $i && $i == *".ali"* ]]; then
    filename="${i%%.ali*}.ali"
    if [ ! -d "$filename" ]; then
      mkdir "$filename"
    fi

    mv "$i" "$filename"
  fi

done
```

For an explanation. Put the dir you want this done on in `dir="/somedir/"`. This will then loop over all files (regular files, directories, symlinks, etc...) in that directory. It then checks if the given file is a regular file containing *ali*. If it is, it checks if a directory with the given filename up to .ali exists, if it doesn't it makes it, then it moves the file to the relevant directory.

If `/somedir/` has the files you list, that produces

```
|-- t_2dri.manual.ali
|   |-- t_2dri.manual.ali_porter.inseq
|   `-- t_2dri.manual.ali_porter.inseq.porter
|-- t_2dri.tm.ali
|   |-- t_2dri.tm.ali_porter.inseq
|   `-- t_2dri.tm.ali_porter.inseq.porter
|-- t_3ezm.manual.ali
|   |-- t_3ezm.manual.ali_porter.inseq
|   `-- t_3ezm.manual.ali_porter.inseq.porter
`-- t_8gep.fast.ali
    |-- t_8gep.fast.ali_porter.inseq
    `-- t_8gep.fast.ali_porter.inseq.porter
```

**Update solution for edited question**

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *".sth"*; do
  [ -f "$i" ] &&  mv "$i" "${i%%.sth*}.sth/"
done
```

Comment: @Strumillo Dots don't matter, see my edit to what it does. "${i%%_porter*} #This will match the longest possible match of _porter* in the string and remove it, leaving everything before it.". The entire script runs through the directory and for every regular file within it (not symlink, not dir), gets the part of the filename before _porter, creates a directory if it doesn't exist, and moves all files of the type there.

Comment: ok, I'm not sure if I fully understand this code, but the thing is I wasn't naming the files and some of them has multiple dots in them such as t_2dri.manual.ali.spinex
t_2dri.manual.ali.spinex.asa
t_2dri.manual.ali.log
etc. sorry I didn't bring it up earlier, casue that was just toy example, but I guess now this code based on i%%_porter* won't work (MY BAD, sorry!!)
the only thing they are supposed to have in common will be *.ali* and I want folders *.ali and the rest (whatever it is, but has the same beggining as the folder name, to put in that folder

Comment: I changed it for filename="${i%%.ali}"
and it doesn't work for me, but maybe it's formatting, I'll check for sure

Comment: @Strumillo I still might be misinterpreting what you want to do, but see if my current edit does it for you, using "${i%%.ali*}.ali"

Comment: thanks, I hope I'll get your code soon, but so far I just did this as simply as I could understood and edited the question

Answer (score 0):

```
cat INPUT.txt | while read FILE ; do
    ## skip blank lines & non-existing files in INPUT.txt
    if [[ $FILE == "" ]] | [[ ! -f $FILE ]] ; then
        continue
    fi

    ## set $BN as dir name
    BN=$(basename $FILE| sed 's/\(.*\)_porter.*/\1/')

    ## make dir if dir does not exist
    if [[ ! -d $BN ]] ; then
        mkdir $BN
    fi

    ## move file to inside dir
    mv $FILE $BN
done
```

Assumptions:

- **INPUT.txt** is the input file & it contains full paths to existing files
   
  (if file is not found, then operation is skipped)
- Unless you change something in the `$BN` variable, directories will be created in the current working directory (i.e. where you run the script)

Comment: seems legit but I totally do not understand what I need in INPUT.txt and why do I need it? is it ls * >INPUT.txt ???

Comment: **INPUT.txt** contains the full paths to all your "_porter.inseq*" files